# connect remote sql (c language)

Tags: mysql, c

I cant connect remote mysql server. After I running the code use gcc, there is undefined reference to mysql

```
administrator@el6116-1:~$ gcc pilihan.c -o pilihan /tmp/cc4UQV0F.o: In
    function `main': pilihan.c:(.text+0x67): undefined reference to
    mysql_init' pilihan.c:(.text+0xe1): undefined reference to
    mysql_real_connect' pilihan.c:(.text+0xf6): undefined reference to
    mysql_error' pilihan.c:(.text+0x135): undefined reference to
    mysql_query' pilihan.c:(.text+0x145): undefined reference to
    mysql_error' pilihan.c:(.text+0x177): undefined reference to
    mysql_use_result' pilihan.c:(.text+0x1c2): undefined reference to
    mysql_fetch_row' pilihan.c:(.text+0x1d9): undefined reference to
    mysql_free_result' pilihan.c:(.text+0x1e5): undefined reference to
    mysql_close' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And here is my code in c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mysql/mysql.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void DataA()
{
    printf( "DataNasabah Dipilih..." );
}
void DataB()
{
    printf( "AdminNasabah Dipilih..." );
}

main() {
 MYSQL *conn;
 MYSQL_RES *res;
 MYSQL_ROW row;

 char *server = "167.205.65.251";
 char *user = "nasabah";
 char *password = "123"; 
 char *database = "wordpress";

 conn = mysql_init(NULL);

    int input;
    printf("MySQl Client Alfred Saut Sibarani 23214038\n");
    printf( "1. Data A\n" );
    printf( "2. Data B\n" );
    printf( "3. Keluar\n" );
    printf( "Pilih Database: " );
    scanf( "%d", &input );

      /* Connection to Database */
      if (!mysql_real_connect(conn, server,
            user, password, database, 0, NULL, 0)) {
          fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
          exit(1);
      }


      /*If input =2 send mysql query*/  
      if (input == 2 && mysql_query(conn, "SELECT * FROM DataNasabah")) 
    {
          fprintf(stderr, "%s\n",  mysql_error(conn));
          exit(1);      
        }

      res = mysql_use_result(conn);

      /* Show table output*/
      printf("Data Nasabah:\n");
      while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) != NULL)
          printf("%s %s %s\n", row[0],row[1],row[2]);

      /* Close connection */
      mysql_free_result(res);
      mysql_close(conn);

}
```

Comment: I think your `#include <mysql/mysql.h>` did not work. check if library exists

Comment: this isn't "I can't connect", this is "mysql library isn't linked". you can't do ANYTHING with mysql in C until the headers/libraries are linked properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <mysql/mysql.h>
```

Did not succeed. You will have to make sure the library is in place and is beeing properly linked.

```
undefined reference to
    mysql_init' pilihan.c:(.text+0xe1)
```

Is a clear indicator that your linking of the library mysql.h failed.

Comment: I do this in my ubuntu terminal gcc -o pilihan pilihan.c `mysql_config --cflags --libs` and it works!  instead gcc pilihan -o pilihan.c it won/t work ; mysql.h location actually in /usr/include/mysql/mysql.h